# Redirect and rewrite - problems with subdir

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a expression in apache:
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 2012/$1 [L]`

My application is at '2012' folder.
I want when someone type www.mysite.com redirect to www.mysite.com/2012
But the URL must continue www.mysite.com

This is done with my current regex .

But i can't access other subdirs to alocate other images, all of these goes to www.mysite.com/2012/newsletter for example.

How i can get www.mysite.com/newsletter working?

Comment: Why can't you use `header("Location: ...")` in `index.php`?

Comment: your current rewrite rule says that you want to redirect EVERY request to 2012 folder. You either have to hardcode all of the pages you want to access before the rewrite rule, or change your current rule to something more flexible

Comment: because i don't want that 2012 folder stay in URL.

Comment: Osny: Can you clarify exactly what URLs you do and don't want rewritten to the 2012 folder? In the end, you have to clarify this to the server - we can't help you do this without knowing exactly the results you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If request starts with 'newsletter' no further rule is processed
RewriteRule ^(newsletter) - [L]

# If first rule doesn't match, rewrite everything not starting with '2012' to the '2012 subfolder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/2012/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /2012/$1 [L]
```

Comment: mysite.com/newsletter will still be redirected to mysite.com/2012

Comment: i can't access an imagem in other subdir.

Comment: Don't downvote while the solution is in progress, that doesn't make any sense. Try the new edit

Comment: Tell me if it works, i dont have any possibility to test this, i also have another solution

Comment: FWIW, he didn't downvote. Coming across this 20 mins after it was posted didn't lead me to think you were still working on the answer. Downvote removed.

Comment: Thx, i try to care about my answers ;)

Comment: Worked! Thank you. can you comment the lines so I can understand your rules?